# How to add a full stop in a directory for a firebase hosted url?

Tags: firebase, hosting, applepay, apple-developer

I'm trying to verify the domain for Apple Developer, who require the verifiable location to be:

`https://[website name].com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt`

The trouble is coming in at the '/.well-known/' segment, I've written the directory as '\.well-known' which works but when I deploy hosting to update the files on my website I can't find it.
I've taken out the "**/.*" from ignore, so it doesn't ignore files with a full stop in. Here's what's left in case I've missed anything:

```
      "hosting": {
        "site": "[website name]",
        "public": "public",
        "cleanUrls": true,
        "ignore": [
          "firebase.json",
          
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by using mkdir to create a hidden folder called '.well-known' in the terminal and showing hidden folders.